heading and lists doesn't work in novel editor
I'm developing a nextjs app and I'm having a hard time configuring a WYSIWYG editor.
I have clone the novel repository and copy the things I need to my project, f.e;
components/advanced-editor.tsx
and all the imports that this file is using
I copied global.css file and prosemirror.ccs too, but the headings and the lists doesn't work. You can see the problem in the next photo.
enter image description here
Maybe is a silly thing, I'm starting to work with nextjs, but I can't figure out what more I need :(
